# Trying to insert new data into a mongo db, which might contain duplicate items intentionally

Tags: python, pandas, pymongo

My code collects data for a bunch of ETFS using Pandas built in data collection algos, and on and end of day basis, with about 5 years of data. The index of my pandas df is a datetime index.

When I created my historical database, everything worked well. Now, I want to update my database daily with a cron job, and for that, I created a time "buffer".

So my thinking is that when I try to insert data that is already in the db, mongo will skip it (after all, I created date as the index). So, with this idea, if one or several of the stocks did not have data for the past few days, by trying to insert data with redundancy, I can have a complete db.

However, I get the following error:

> DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: ETFs.EEM
>   index: *id* dup key: { : new Date(1524700800000) }

My understanding was that mongo should have skipped this. What's wrong with this code?

```
def insert_to_mongo():
    for x in etfs.keys():
        print 'Processing ' + x
        data_points = len(etfs[x])
        for i in range(data_points):
            data = ({
                '_id': etfs[x].index[i],
                'open': float(etfs[x].iloc[i]['open']),
                'high': float(etfs[x].iloc[i]['high']),
                'low': float(etfs[x].iloc[i]['low']),
                'close': float(etfs[x].iloc[i]['close']),
                'adj close': float(etfs[x].iloc[i]['adj close']),
                'volume': float(etfs[x].iloc[i]['volume']),
                })
            collection = db[x]
            collection.insert_one(data)
    print 'Inserted data successfully'
```

Comment: There is a document existing in the collection with that date for its index. You can wrap `collection.insert_one(data)` in a try/except block to catch DuplicateKeyError when they happen. If you want to do an update when a duplicate key exists, you will want `upsert` instead of this approach.

Comment: Thank you Oluwafemi. You should post your comment as an answer so I can give you the credit. Cheers!